# Android in-app billing: Is it really necessary to create a local service?

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, android-service

The [official documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/market/billing/billing_integrate.html#billing-service) says that "Your application must have a local Service to facilitate messaging between your application and Android Market."

My question is, is this is really necessary? And if yes, why?

Wouldn't it be possible to simply bind to the MarketBillingService from an Activity's onCreate method without having to creating a local service first?

Having to create a local service that forward the requests to the remote MarketBillingService just seems a bit over-complicated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree that the In-App Billing example application has a number of layers to it that seem unnecessary, but the idea of using a Service to interact with Market is a good one.  This is because the process is very asynchronous (and can take a good amount of time) and some events are generated outside the workflow of a user purchase.

While the user will be interacting with some Market UI while deciding whether to purchase the "item", after this process is over there is a long back-and-forth between your app and the market app to authorize and finalize the transaction, many steps delayed while Market communicates with its servers.  You don't want to hold the user up and force them to wait on that Activity simply so you can complete the purchase.  You want that to be in a Service so the user can move around in the app, or leave it completely for awhile, and still be able to finalize the purchase and download the appropriate purchased content without fear of your process being removed.

Also, there are many events that may come into your application if purchases are canceled or otherwise rejected that can happen LONG after the initial purchase back-and-forth, and the user may be doing something completely different or not have their phone awake at all at that time.  You want to be able to handle these events without having to pop up an Activity.

Bottom line, it's a long-running background process...which is what Services were designed for.

HTH

Comment: The Dungeons sample app calls `mBillingService.unbind()` from the main activity's onDestroy method. So the life span of the local service should be the same as that of the main activity. Also the local service does not seem to spawn a thread of its own so all work is done in the main thread of the process. So what's the point of having the local service? Are you saying it's all about telling Android to "please don't kill my process"? IMO a service does not even guarantee that.

Comment: The service in the example doesn't run in a bound context, and the call to `unbind()` has nothing to do with it's lifecycle here.  It's only bound for the Activity to obtain a reference and call methods directly on it.  The service is started as a result of receiving Broadcasts mostly, and runs until a given operation is complete.  The point is, if you bind all the actions from the Receiver to an Activity, what happens when the user leaves that Activity?  The events happen over too long a period of time.  With a Service it doesn't matter; the user can leave and the job still gets done.

Comment: Plus, when one of those other asynchronous events comes in, you don't have to start an Activity (that'll tick off a user) or try to handle it directly in the BroadcastReceiver, which means you'll have to do the whole thing synchronously or the receiver instance will die.  IMO, the real fluff in that example is in the Handler and other layers required to interact with the Service.

Comment: So the local service is needed primarily (exclusively?) for processing the information that is received by the BroadcastReceiver? It is not needed at all for invoking the remote MarketBillingService from the main activity? If that's the case then I think I get it. Thanks.

Comment: Primarily, yes; and since you CAN bind to services, they take advantage of that so the application can make requests through direct method calls instead of constructing unruly intents with lots of extras.

Comment: There is an open source [AndroidBillingLibrary](https://github.com/robotmedia/AndroidBillingLibrary) available on github. It seems to do all the work in the BillingReceiver without starting a local service. BillingReceiver calls on BillingController which calls on TransactionManager which stores the information in a sqlite database. Is this library seriously flawed then?

Comment: IMO, it's not awful.  It does still queue/run requests using a local Service instance.  `BillingController` ends up running a lot of code directly in `BrodcastReceiver.onReceive()`, which I'm not a fan of.  I'm also not sure I agree with the Activity maintaining an observer between create/destroy, instead of just between pause/resume.  But it does seem to call down to a Service in cases where it would be considered necessary.